# Using a switch statement to create a new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a switch statement to taken input data from an HTML text-box.

Thus far, it has been successful.

My next step is the following: if the user enters the number 20, I would like to input new data into a variable called "coordinates" so it may be used throughout the program.

So far, I am unable to use data from the variable "coordinates". Any suggestions?

```
switch(Number($('#inputdata').val())){
case 20:
var coordinates = {
      latt1: 12,
      lngg2: 34
}
break;
}
```

Comment: Define var coordinates above and just do coordinates = { }; (remove var) in switch.

Comment: you should declare the coordinates variable outside of `switch` statment. Just set the variable value inside `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your variable global?

```
var coordinates;

switch(Number($('#inputdata').val())){
case 20:
coordinates = {
      latt1: 12,
      lngg2: 34
}
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save this input data into your coordinate variable

```
var coordinates = {
      latt1: Number($('#inputdata').val()),
      lngg2: 34
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your variable outside the switch statement. I would think about putting it in a closure like so:

```
function getCoordinates(element){
    var coordinates = {};
    // the closure is an immediately invoked function
    // that sets the coordinates variable according to
    // to the switch statements;
    var coord = function(){
        switch(parseInt(element.val()))
        // case statements
        coordinates = {"latt1":12,"lngg2":34};
    }();
    // ^^ means run this function now
    return coordinates;
}
```

Then you can just assign the return of the outer function to a variable.

```
var c = getCoordinates($('#inputdata'));
```

The benefits here are that you don't pollute the global namespace with a global variable, your coordinates variable is private data, and you can easily modify the function params if you don't want to have a ton of switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that declaring the variable outside the switch and assign it is not a good idea, in the long run it can make thing harder to debug.

I would make a function that return the desired value and assign it to coordinated

```
function inputToCoordinate (inputValue) {
  switch(inputValue) {
    case 20:
      return {
        latt1: 12,
        lngg2: 34
      }
    // ...

  }
}

var input = $('#inputdata').val();
var coordinates = inputToCoordinate(parseInt(input, 10))
```

Also I'm not a big fan of **switch** statement, but that is another discussion.